# Change image with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change image when I click the link. I have code below. First click it is working. But in second click, it is not.

menu_span is "link id"
menu_image is "image id"

```
$(function() {  
  $("#menu_span").click( function(){

        if(document.getElementById('menu_image').src ="images/arti.jpg")
        {
            document.getElementById('menu_image').src ="images/eksi.jpg";                   
        }

        else

        if(document.getElementById('menu_image').src ="images/eksi.jpg")
        {
            document.getElementById('menu_image').src ="images/arti.jpg";

        }           
    }
  );
});
```

it is working like below. But I dont want to use "i2"

```
var i2=0;   
  $("#slider_span").click( function(){
      if(i2==0)
        {
            document.getElementById('slider_image').src ="images/eksi.jpg"; 
            document.getElementById('slider_div').style.display="inline-block";
            i2=1;
        }
        else
        if(i2==1)
        {
            document.getElementById('slider_image').src ="images/arti.jpg";
            document.getElementById('slider_div').style.display="none";
            i2=0;
        }

    }
  );
```

please help!

Answer (score 2):

Use `==`, not `=` to check equality :

```
if (document.getElementById('menu_image').src == "images/arti.jpg") {
    document.getElementById('menu_image').src ="images/eksi.jpg";                   
} else if(document.getElementById('menu_image').src == "images/eksi.jpg") {
    document.getElementById('menu_image').src ="images/arti.jpg";
}
```

But instead of testing the state of the element, you'd better store it in a variable :

```
$(function() {
  var nbchanges = 0;
  $("#menu_span").click( function(){
      $('#menu_image').prop('src', (nbchanges++)%2 ? "images/arti.jpg" : "images/eksi.jpg");
  });
});
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/IgAhoja/1/)

Comment: Are you sure the src is one of those ?

Comment: Yes both of them in the same file.

Comment: @fatry Maybe will it be clearer with the demonstration ? See edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use === to avoid type conversion.